# is there a way to input a list from clipboard and as a list? or any other solution to do the same?

Tags: ios, applescript

I have a code in AppleScript, which is supposed to have an input from last copied text separated by commas. i have made so that script recognise the copied as list.

have a look to my example

i have a list of names

**Apple Watch**

**iPhone**

**iPad**

**macBook**

in order to recognise as a list i have made in to readable list like
"Apple Watch","iPhone","iPad","macBook"
and have copied to my clipboard expecting the to have automatically pasted to my code as input. But unfortunately the code doesn't recognise each string separately and gives the same output like this: *"Apple Watch","iPhone","iPad","macBook"* instead of this:

**Apple Watch**

**iPhone**

**iPad**

**macBook**

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set Storage to get clipboard
    set theList to {Storage}
    tell application "System Events"
        set varX to 1
        set condition to 0
        repeat until condition = length of theList
            set varName to item varX of theList
            keystroke of varName
            delay 0.2
            keystroke return
            delay 0.2
            set varX to varX + 1
            set condition to condition + 1
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

the same thing will work according to my need if i paste that list in the place Storage
but i need to happen it automatically without me pasting the list everytime by opening the script.

i apologise for becoming very wordy
Can anybody please give me solution?

Comment: You are just making the text into a single item list - are you asking how to create a list from the text containing comma separated items (or paragraphs)?

Comment: this code will work if i paste this in the place of Storage in the code but i wanted the code to recognise it automatically from the clipboard without me pasting it everytime. is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: The correct term is `the clipboard` and not just `clipboard` (unless that was a typo), but you will need to make a list from the comma separated text yourself.

Comment: @RassyRaoof Can you tell us what you're trying to achieve ?  Obviously, you're trying to insert those words into _Safari_; are they intending to be inserted into the address bar, or into a web page ?  If the latter, what is the web page ?

Answer (score 0):

As understand you have in the clipboard the text **"Apple Watch","iPhone","iPad","macBook"**. And, you want to keystroke it line by line in the Safari window. If this is case, then you have just to replace **commas** with **returns** in the clipboard's text, then keystroke this whole replaced text:

```
set Storage to the clipboard
set {ATID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, ","}
set theList to text items of Storage
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
set theList to theList as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID

tell application "System Events"
    set frontmost of process "Safari" to true
    keystroke theList
end tell
```

If your task is to **fill in individual fields of some form** in Safari, then time **delays** are needed there and the text should be sent in parts. More or less like this:

```
set Storage to the clipboard
set {ATID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, ","}
set theList to text items of Storage
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID

tell application "System Events"
    set frontmost of process "Safari" to true
    repeat with anItem in theList
        keystroke (contents of anItem) & return
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
end tell
```